Why can't I add a simple object to a simple array in Dart?
I'm trying to learn Dart and Flutter and am struggling with something as simple as adding an object to an array.
class Counter {
  String label;
  var counts = [];

  Counter({required this.label, this.counts = const []});
}

class Count {
  double latitude;
  double longitude;
  DateTime date;

  Count({required this.latitude, required this.longitude, required this.date});
}

class CounterCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Counter counter;

  const CounterCard({super.key, required this.counter});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Text('${counter.label}'),
        Text('${counter.counts.length}'),
        IconButton.filled(onPressed: onPressed, icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle))
      ],
    );
  }

  onPressed() {
    print('Add count');
    counter.counts.add(Count(
      latitude: 0.0,
      longitude: 0.0,
      date: DateTime.now()
    ));
  }
}

Pressing the button prints 'Add count', but the UI is not updated counter.counts.length should increase.
I believe this is just me not understanding the state, so please help me understand.

Use setState(() {}) method after the list is updated to update your ui the simplest way. But if you want to update continuously use ChangeNotifier or Providers.
Addition
As I can see you are using a Stateless class setState will be not accessible in your class. I have updated your overall code.
I have changed your counter class as well as the counts variable was constant and const assignments are not updatable.
class Counter {
  String label;
  List<Count>? counts;

  Counter({required this.label, List<Count>? counts}) : counts = counts ?? [];
}

class Count {
  double latitude;
  double longitude;
  DateTime date;

  Count({required this.latitude, required this.longitude, required this.date});
}

class CounterCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final Counter counter;

  const CounterCard({super.key, required this.counter});

  @override
  State<CounterCard> createState() => _CounterCardState();
}

class _CounterCardState extends State<CounterCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Text('${widget.counter.label}'),
        Text('${widget.counter.counts?.length ?? "0"}'),
        IconButton.filled(onPressed: onPressed, icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle))
      ],
    );
  }

  onPressed() {
    print('Add count');
    setState(() {
      widget.counter.counts
          ?.add(Count(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0, date: DateTime.now()));
    });
  }
}


Thanks, wrapping the increment in setState gives med the error: The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'CounterCard'.
Do I need to implement the UI manually?

You have to use the Stateful widget as you are updating your UI.  i have updated your code and edited my answer check this out. please try this if it works for you.

Thanks, I was suspecting that using a Stateless Widget was the problem.
I couldn't figure out how to access the final counter property from the state, so I tried passing it through the constructor, which was giving me a warning. Can you explain where the "widget"-accessor comes from in the state? i.e. widget.counter.label. Is that some secret under-the-hood-thing?

Also, it was not necessary to change the Counter class, as I don't want it to be nullable. Empty array means count is zero.
I know this is a weird way to make a counter, but if course it's a part of something bigger. ;-)

Your CounterCard is a stateful widget and if you want to access the properties of the widget class in your state class you can use a widget accessor. widget is nothing but a reference to your CounterCard class. Also if you don't want to be nullable just use var in place of List?,  it will still work.
